# Binding Dictionary Value to Dependency Property of a UserControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I'm trying to bind a Value from a Dictionary set as an itemsource of a tabcontrol to a DependencyProperty of a UserControl which is held within my TabControl.ContentTemplate.

For the life of me I can't get it to bind, I have a strong feeling it may have someting to do with the DataContext of the userControl 'EnvironmentStateView' which in this instance is a viewmodel.

In a separate TextBlock the binding to the dictionary key works for each item in the collection but unfortunately thats it.

EnvironmentCollectionView.xaml

```
<TabControl Name="EnvironmentCollectionTabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding environmentCollection}">
      <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
                <local:EnvironmentStateView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" EnvironmentObject="{Binding Value}" EnvironmentKey="{Binding Key}"></local:EnvironmentStateView>
          </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

EnvironmentStateView.xaml

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for EnvironmentStateView.xaml
/// </summary>
[Export(typeof(EnvironmentStateView))]
public partial class EnvironmentStateView : UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Environment object dependency property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnvironmentObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "EnvironmentObject",
            typeof(Framework.Environment),
            typeof(EnvironmentStateView),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    /// <summary>
    /// Environment key dependency property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnvironmentKeyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "EnvironmentKey",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(EnvironmentStateView),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public EnvironmentStateView()
    {
        // Set data context
        this.DataContext = new EnvironmentStateViewModel();
        // Initialise
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the environment object
    /// </summary>
    public Framework.Environment EnvironmentObject
    {
        get { return (Framework.Environment)GetValue(EnvironmentObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EnvironmentObjectProperty, value); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the environment key
    /// </summary>
    public string EnvironmentKey
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(EnvironmentObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EnvironmentObjectProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

The DataContext for the environmentstateview is set to a view model, though removing this means it datacontext is null so I guess it is not inheriting anything to begin with.

My goal was to have the environmentCollectionView use an environmentCollection Observable dictionary in its viewmodel, bind it as an itemsource to a tabctronol and then pass on the individual environment objects within the collection to separate usercontrols to handle specific views / visuals associated with the environment objects themselves.

The only way i thought i could do this was to pass the dictionary Value as a dependency property so each usercontrol can do its thing :), Granted this might be a terrible way to do so.

Any help is appreciated

Regards Wolfe

EDIT* Changed UserControl to EnvironmentStateView

EDIT* Right after fixing the previous error I than noticed some more binding error info coming up

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Key' property not found on 'object' ''EnvironmentStateViewModel' (HashCode=63276897)'. BindingExpression:Path=Key; DataItem='EnvironmentStateViewModel' (HashCode=63276897); target element is 'EnvironmentStateView' (Name=''); target property is 'EnvironmentKey' (type 'String')

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Value' property not found on 'object' ''EnvironmentStateViewModel' (HashCode=32159097)'. BindingExpression:Path=Value; DataItem='EnvironmentStateViewModel' (HashCode=32159097); target element is 'EnvironmentStateView' (Name=''); target property is 'EnvironmentObject' (type 'Environment')
```

Now Key and Value are obviously not in the EnvironmentStateViewModel which i guess is the current data context.

I intentionally misspelled the EnvironmentTagTextBlock binding to Keyy which gave me the binding error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Keyy' property not found on 'object' ''KeyValuePair`2' (HashCode=-459631492)'. BindingExpression:Path=Keyy; DataItem='KeyValuePair`2' (HashCode=-459631492); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

So my guess is that i need to somehow change my DataItem from EnvironmentStateViewModel to
KeyValuePair`2 perhaps but I have no idea how or whether I probably should lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EnvironmentObjectProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "EnvironmentObject",
        typeof(Framework.Environment),
        typeof(EnvironmentStateView),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Shouldn't the parent class be `EnvironmentStateView`instead of `UserControl`?

Comment: Gaahh you are correct, that will teach me to lazily copy over some code :). Unfortunately made no differance to the original problem though :S.